# docker mysql UnknownHostException in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I am using spring boot  with docker. When i Run **docker-compose.yaml** file it shows bellow error in mysql:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
 at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
```

I have user bellow like:

1. In **docker-compose.yaml** file I have use bellow code..

   ```
   services:
     mysql:
       image: mysql:latest
       hostname: mysql
       restart: always
       ports:
         - 3306:3306
       environment:
         MYSQL_DATABASE: accountdb
         MYSQL_USER: root
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
       volumes:
         - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
         - ./src/main/resources/db/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
       command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql

      my-service:
        image: myimage
        mem_limit: 700m
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"   
       depends_on:    
        - mysql
   ```
2. In Spring boot a**pplicaiton.ym**l file:

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: account-opening
     datasource:
       url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/accountdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
       username: root
       password: 123



     jpa:
       hibernate:
         ddl-auto: create
       show-sql: true
       generate-ddl: true
     h2:
       console:
         enabled: true
   ```

what is the wrong of my code? Please help me

Comment: Can you verify that your MySql container is actually running? You might get the error your get, if the database container fails to start. A good way to troubleshoot is to run `docker-compose up` in the foreground. I.e. without the `-d` option. Then you'll see any error messages that pop up.

Comment: AFAIK mysql is written in C++. The error you are showing comes from a java program so I'm positively sure it comes from the container running your springboot application, not from the one holding mysql. That precision being made: `what is wrong with my code?` is not an acceptable question on SO and listed as the [number one reason to close a question as off-topic](/help/on-topic). Where is you docker file for `my-service`? How do you launch your app? What debuging steps did you take? Is mysql really running? If yes, can you ping the mysql container from `my-service`? ...

Comment: PS: you are using the `mysql` official docker image a wrong way to initialize your data (unless your very perfectly know what you are doing). I suggest you read the [documentation on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), remove your `command` on the service to get back to default and move your `init.sql` script inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the container. I would actually bet that mysql is not starting on a second run because of your `command` customization.

Comment: @HansKilian it showing restarting...

Comment: If it's restarting, that means that it's failed to start. Since you have `restart: always`, it'll just keep trying to start it forever. What error message does it give when it fails?

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a volumes section in your docker-compose.yml file every time you use volumes. Also, double check if your database initialization script can be used in docker-compose like that.